# How to insert a value at any position using a dictionary in C#

Tags: c#

I have a car class and it has get and set methods. It includes both importing vehicle information and exporting that vehicle information. I use dictionary to store all vehicle information. I have created a car input function in the list class:

```
Dictionary<string, Car> Dic = new Dictionary<string, Car>();
public void InputCar()
{
    Car car = new Car();
    car.Input();
    Dic.Add(car.BienSo1, car);
}
```

And now I want to insert at any position that I enter to put new car information into the dictionary, how will I do it?

Example:

```
Number Plate : 21112
Name Car : Honda
Number Plate : 33333
Name Car : Suzu
Insert at position 1 into the dictionary
Enter to put new car information
Number Plate : 21112
Name Car : Honda
Number Plate : 11111
Name Car : Toyota
Number Plate : 33333
Name Car : Suzuki
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try looking at an [OrderedDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.aspx) for this instead of a normal dictionary. [OrderedDictionary.Insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.insert.aspx) will let you to specify the index at which the key will be inserted. Normal dictionaries use a key instead of an index, so this is not possible.